# Why neoantigen vaccine (and vaccine in general) is often delivered by subcutaneous injection instead of direct injection into the tumor site?

Tags: vaccine, tumors, antigen

I read that neoantigen vaccine is often delivered by subcutaneous or intramuscular injection (for example, as mentioned by doi: 10.3389/fimmu.2018.01499). However, I do not understand why it is delivered in such a way. Why direct injection into the tumor site or into a nearby lymph node is not used in clinical setttings?

Here is the answer provided by ChatGPT 4.0, I do not think that the answer is completely correct even though I am not sure which part is not correct.

[image]

Comment: The immune system would, if it was working „correctly“, eliminate any tumor (and in fact they eliminate most of the tumours, which is why humans with immune deficiencies are much more likely to develop clinically relevant tumours). The tumour achieves this by many strategies, some of them involve tending the tumour microenvironment „immune-cold“, meaning immune cells don’t do their job properly inside tumour. The purpose of the neoantigen vaccine is to reactivate the immune system, so you want to inject somewhere where you do get a good immune response (which is definitely not in the tumor).

Comment: [cont‘d]. All other „normal“ vaccines that stimulate/activate the immune system are given intramuscularly or subcutaneously, so there is good evidence that this is safe and effective, hence it is the standard right now. In theory, you could inject in tumour-draining lymph nodes but that is a) technical challenging and b) since those are usually located deep within the body can cause further harm. Finally, in the metastatic disease usually one is careful where to puncture / biopsy because there is a real risk of biopsy / puncture track metastasis if you hit tumour tissue

Comment: Also, not all cancers form tumors. The blood cancers such as leukemia, for example, do not.

Comment: The ChatGPT answer is actually quite correct and makes the same points @Narusan makes.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

It seems only the "Immune response" part of the answer given by ChatGPT is incorrect because the number of immune cells at the injection site is quite negligible: skin is the largest organ in human body and the number of immune cells in skin is not significantly greater than in other parts of the body (PMC10623016/). 

Also, the immunosuppressive effect of cancer can reduce the effectiveness of vaccine in a mouse model (PMC3538956), and intravenous injection of vaccine can induce acute myopericarditis in mouse model (PMC8436386).